# check that a list only contains values from another list

Tags: java

I have a list

["Pa12", "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12", "Fi12", "Co12"]

and I want to check if the list only contains "Pa12" and "Co12". It can contain one or both of these values but not neither. So in the above example the check would fail but in the example:

["Pa12", "Pa12, "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12"]

and the example:

["Pa12", "Pa12"]

the check would pass. How would I achieve this?

Comment: 1) Remove each allowed value from the list 2) Check if the list is empty

Comment: Or just `new HashSet<>(listOfAllowedValues).containsAll(list)`. Even better would be to use a `Set` of allowed values in the first place. If you know for sure that the list will always be as small as two value, you can use the list directly, `listOfAllowedValues.containsAll(list)`. But code tends to live longer than expected, so it’s better to use the scaleable solution.

Comment: Your sentence “It can contain one or both of these values but not neither.” seems to create confusion among the answerers. What you actually mean is (apparently), “Each elements must be either `"Pa12"` or `"Co12"` (and nothing else).”

Comment: Please check my answer to see if I properly understood your question.  There seems to be some confusion.  It may be me. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is ambiguous. Your prose does not match your example data. Let’s look at two cases you may have intended.

### Input contains at least one of our target elements

> It can contain one or both of these values but not neither.

Use streams to examine each element of your list. Stop when finding the first match.

```
List< String > input = List.of( "Pa12", "Pa12", "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12" ) ;
List< String > target = List.of( "Pa12", "Pa12" ) ;

boolean hit = target.stream().anyMatch( ( String s ) -> input.contains ( s ) ) ;
```

> true

We can shorten that by using a method reference.

```
boolean hit = target.stream().anyMatch( input :: contains ) ;
```

### Input contains nothing but one or more of our target elements

But your example data seems to suggest you want something else. Apparently you want to know if the input list contains one or more of the target elements *and* contains nothing else.

We can accomplish that goal in two steps. First, be sure the input is not empty. If empty, return `false`. Secondly, make a `Set` of your input. This eliminates duplicates. And `Set` offers a handy [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection)) method. We can remove all of our target elements from the set. If anything remains in the set, then return `false`. If the set is empty, return `true`.

```
if ( input.isEmpty() ) { return false ; }
Set< String > set = new HashSet<> ( input ) ;
set.removeAll( target ) ;
return set.isEmpty() ;
```

Comment: sorry about the ambiguity. Yes it was example 2 of what you said

Comment: I'm still confused.  Doesn't your stream solution return `true` if you put say, `"Fi12"` in the input list since it is not in the target list. Isn't that considered a failure as stated in the question?

Comment: @WJS As I said up top, the Question is ambiguous. The prose of the Question does not match the example data. So in the *first* case of my Answer I am testing for "contains at least one of our targets", and that is all. I based that test on the quoted prose from the Question. Your comment is covered by the *second* case of my Answer, "contains nothing but at least one of our targets". The comparison logic of each case is summarized in the heading.

Comment: Still, `target.containsAll(input)` is simpler. Or `new HashSet<>(target) .containsAll(input)` if target is a large list. The assumption that an empty input should result in `false` is not backed by the question as given.

Comment: No, your last Comment is incorrect on both of its points. A call to `containsAll` does *not* meet requirement of “one or both of these values but not neither“. And, an empty list returning `false` *does* fulfill that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to tackle your problem is to turn your list into a [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which is a data structure that only contains one copy of each value in it. Hence regardless of the number of the same elements in your list the set will only contain one instance of it.

If your list is of data type `List` this is done by

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(myList);
```

or if it is an array

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
```

Then it will be an easy check

```
boolean myCheck(Set<String> mySet) 
{
    mySet.discard("Pa12");
    mySet.discard("Co12");
    return mySet.size() == 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `discard` method in `Set` and instead of `.size() == 0` you can use `.isEmpty()`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using a `set` for the target list as it is more efficient.  A list would also work.

```
List<String> base = List.of("Pa12", "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12", "Co12");
Set<String> target = Set.of("Pa12", "Co12");
```

This checks the base list against the target list and makes the necessary inversions of the `booleans` to correct the result.

```
 List<List<String>> baseLists = List.of(
         List.of("Pa12", "Pa12", "Pa12"),
         List.of("Pa12", "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12", "Co12"),
         List.of("Pa12", "Co12", "Pa12", "Co12", "fi12", "Co12"));
 Set<String> target = Set.of("Pa12", "Co12");

 for (List<String> base : baseLists) {
     boolean hasAtLeastOne = !list.stream()
             .anyMatch(s -> !target.contains(s));
     System.out.println(list + " -> " + hasAtLeastOne);
 }
```

prints

```
[Pa12, Pa12, Pa12] -> true
[Pa12, Co12, Pa12, Co12, Co12] -> true
[Pa12, Co12, Pa12, Co12, fi12, Co12] -> false
```